# JavaFx: fxmlLoader.load returns Parent?

Tags: java, javafx

I have ScrollPane at root level in fxml file and I have the following code:

```
import javafx.scene.Parent;
...
parent = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(getFxmlStream("my.fxml"));
if (parent.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Parent.class)){
    System.out.println("THIS IS PARENT");
}else{
    System.out.println("THIS IS NOT PARENT");//THIS WILL BE PRINTEED
}
```

Why what load function returns is not assignable from Parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadocs for `isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-):

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

So you are testing if the runtime type of the object you got from the FXML loader is equal to, or a *superclass* of, `Parent`. If it is a strict subclass of `Parent` (`VBox`, `BorderPane` etc), then this will be `false`.

If you want to test if the value you have is some kind of `Parent`, the usual way to do that is with `instanceof`:

```
if (parent instanceof Parent)){
    System.out.println("THIS IS PARENT");
}else{
    System.out.println("THIS IS NOT PARENT");//THIS WILL BE PRINTEED
}
```

If you want to use `getClass()` and `isAssignableFrom()`, then you have things the wrong way around:

```
if (Parent.class.isAssignableFrom(parent.getClass())){
    System.out.println("THIS IS PARENT");
}else{
    System.out.println("THIS IS NOT PARENT");//THIS WILL BE PRINTEED
}
```

though I recommend the standard `instanceof` approach anyway.

Also note that you can use FXML to pretty much load any object, so there is certainly no guarantee that what you get is a subclass of `Parent`.

Comment: My mistake was that ScrollPane is subclass (ScrollPane extends Parent) but I checked if ScrollPane is a superclass (Parent extends ScrollPane)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `S.class.isAssignableFrom(T.class)` is true if and only if  `T t = ... ; S obj = t ;` will compile.